# Inflated view methods not working after inflating the view

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I have a function which inflates a layout and is supposed to manipulate the views contained within the layout. The layout's base element is a `ConstraintLayout`.

The fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    public void myFunction() {
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
        TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
        t.setText("Some other text"); // nothing happens
        t.setTextColor(0xFF0000FF); // nothing happens
        t.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000); // nothing happens
        Log.d("call", "myFunction() was called");
    }
}
```

The layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F0F0F0"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout/>
```

The code compiles and runs successfully, but when I call `myFunction()` nothing happens to the `TextView`, while the log statement logs successfully. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's nothing weird in your code but where do you add the View v?

Comment: It is the base view (the ConstraintLayout) in fragment_home.

Comment: can you please add the full code of your fragment ?

Comment: I added the relevant code (full code is over a thousand lines).

Comment: the LayoutInflater used to instantiate a view from xml file but you must add this view in the main layout or dialog or something else to get an effect. and im looking for this part on your code

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "add this view in the main layout"?

Comment: if we see the parameters of the method we find `inflate (@resLayout, ViewGroup, attacheToRoot)`

in your example you didn't specify the ViewGroup not problem  here. but you must use `example rootView.addView(v)`;

Comment: What should `rootView` be in the example you've given? Note that this XML is contained in a fragment (`fragment_home.xml`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230450/discussion-between-shay-kin-and-wais-kamal).